# Why does my toString() method not return my Singly Linked List in a string format?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a toString() method that returns the values in my singly-linked list in a string format by iterating through the list. See below for the SinglyLinkedList.java file which contains the toString() method.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Your implementation of a Singly-Linked List.
 */
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> {
    
    /*
     * Do not add new instance variables or modify existing ones.
     */
    private SinglyLinkedListNode<T> head;
        private SinglyLinkedListNode<T> tail;
        private int size;
    
    /*
     * Do not add a constructor.
     */

    /**
     * Adds the element to the front of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(1) time.
     *
     * @param data the data to add to the front of the list
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if data is null
     */
        public void addToFront(T data) {
        if (data == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null");
        }
            SinglyLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data);
        if (head == null){
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else{
            newNode.setNext(head);
            head = newNode;
        }
        size++;
        }

    /**
     * Adds the element to the back of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(1) time.
     *
     * @param data the data to add to the back of the list
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if data is null
     */
    public void addToBack(T data) {
        if (data == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null");
        }
            if (head == null){
            head = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data);
        }
        else {
            SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
            while (current.getNext() != null){
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data));
        }
        size++;
        }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the first data of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(1) time.
     *
     * @return the data formerly located at the front of the list
     * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if the list is empty
     */
        public T removeFromFront() {
        if (head == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("You cannot remove elements from the front of an empty list");
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> var = head;
            head = head.getNext();
        size--; 
        return var.getData();
        }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the last data of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(n) time.
     *
     * @return the data formerly located at the back of the list
     * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if the list is empty
     */
        public T removeFromBack() {
            if (head == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("You cannot remove an element from the back of an empty list");
        }
        else if (head.getNext() == null){
            SinglyLinkedListNode<T> var = head;
            head = null;
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
        while (current.getNext().getNext() != null){
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> var = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(null);
        size--;
        return var.getData();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the head node of the list.
     *
     * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
     * you have direct access to the variable.
     *
     * @return the node at the head of the list
     */
        public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> getHead() {
        // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
            return head;
        }

    /**
     * Returns the tail node of the list.
     *
     * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
     * you have direct access to the variable.
     *
     * @return the node at the tail of the list
     */
        public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> getTail() {
        // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
            return tail;
        }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the list.
     *
     * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
     * you have direct access to the variable.
     *
     * @return the size of the list
     */
        public int size() {
        // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
            return size;
        }
    
    public String toString() {
        String answer = "";
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
        while (current != null){
            answer += current + " ";
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SinglyLinkedList<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
        list.addToFront(1);
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```

And for my SinglyLinkedListNode.java file...

```
/**
 * Node class used for implementing the SinglyLinkedList.
 *
 * DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE!!
 *
 * @author CS 1332 TAs
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class SinglyLinkedListNode<T> {

        private T data;
        private SinglyLinkedListNode<T> next;

    /**
     * Constructs a new SinglyLinkedListNode with the given data and next node
     * reference.
     *
     * @param data the data stored in the new node
     * @param next the next node in the list
     */
        SinglyLinkedListNode(T data, SinglyLinkedListNode<T> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

    /**
     * Creates a new SinglyLinkedListNode with only the given data.
     *
     * @param data the data stored in the new node
     */
        SinglyLinkedListNode(T data) {
            this(data, null);
        }

    /**
     * Gets the data.
     *
     * @return the data
     */
        T getData() {
            return data;
        }

    /**
     * Gets the next node.
     *
     * @return the next node
     */
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

    /**
     * Sets the next node.
     *
     * @param next the new next node
     */
        void setNext(SinglyLinkedListNode<T> next) {
            this.next = next;
    }

}
```

Whenever I call the toString() method from my SinglyLinkedList class, I get the following printed in my command prompt.

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Rby.png)

Does anyone know why I do not see the value "1" which I am adding to the front of the linkedlist prior to calling the toString() method? And if so, what can I do to fix it? Instead, it keeps printing the node object.

Comment: Your `SinglyLinkedList.toString()` implicitly invokes `SinglyLinkedListNode.toString()`, but such a method is not defined. Either implement it in `SinglyLinkedListNode`, or use e.g. `answer += current.getData() + " ";` in  `SinglyLinkedList.toString()` to show the data directly instead of implicitly invoking `current.toString()`

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant and absolutely required to describe your problem.

Comment: Also, as per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Adding a `@Overrides` to your `toString()` may help you understand what's going on

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have an object 'current' of type SinglyLinkedList whose toString method is not overridden.

```
public String toString() {
    String answer = "";
    SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
    while (current != null){
        answer += current + " ";
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

If you cannot override toString method in SinglyLinkedListNode class then you can modify the while loop to:

```
while(current != null){
    answer += current.getData() + " ";
    current = current.getNext();
}
```

Assuming your T has appropriate toString() method overridden.

To make the code more efficient you can use StringBuilder rather than concatenating strings.

```
public String toString() {
    //String answer = " ";
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
    while (current != null){
        //answer += current + " ";
        answer.append(current.getData());
        answer.append(" ");
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return answer.toString();
```

}